# Eclipse Debugging Remote Java Application hangs

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging

I am attempting to connect the Eclipse to a remote Tomcat application.
Eclipse is able to establish a connect, and I can see the running threads but my break points are never triggered.

Instead it seems the Tomcat application hangs until I disconnect the debugger, at which point the application continues to run.

I added log lines to my Tomcat application at my break points so I know they should get triggered.

Efforts taken so far:

I have modified `/../tomcat/bin/startup.sh` to include

```
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8082 
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

and

`exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"`

and `/../tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`

From: `JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"`

To: `JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=*:$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"`

This has previously worked without any issues.

Java Version:
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-1, mixed mode)

Eclipse Version:
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200

Comment: Sounds like `suspend=y`

Comment: Your breakpoints might get ignored if you compiled the application without line numbers (and the breakpoint is not at the start of the method).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, could you elaborate a little more?